# JS: displaying an infinitely long coordinating system (grid)

Tags: javascript, html, web, coordinate-systems, infinity

I would like to display an infinitely long coordinating system/grid (X and Y axes), which contains an endless amount of square (something like DIVs), using JavaScript. I don't have any idea where to start. It seems to me like a really hard problem to solve. There are so many factors of which I don't have an idea to build them, such as:

- structuring them in an HTML element tree
- using the right elements (probably SVG elements)
- giving the grid a fluid scroll
- coordinating the loading of each element (if it has to be displayed)

I am sure there are JavaScript libraries, that can help me doing it, but I don't know any of these.

What would be a good way to start with?

---

Here is the concept of my grid:

```
(Y axis)
^
|  |      |      |
|--+------+------+---
| E| SQURE| SQURE| SQ
|  |      |      |
|--+------+------+---
| E| SQURE| SQURE| SQ
|  |      |      |
|--+------+------+---
| E| SQURE| SQURE| SQ
+--------------------> (X axis)
```

Comment: what exactly are you wanting to use this functionality for? Graphing? Is so we might be able to offer better options/libraries for use.

Comment: yup something like graphing (but more like drawing on the grid, from one of the squaring corners to another) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While in the comments you said something similar to graphing, I would really give something like [kineticjs](http://kineticjs.com/) a peek. It uses canvas's and could be a bit of overkill for what you are attempting but it's a great resource that has many uses but since you've requested a grid, here is a question over that as well [Kinetic.js – creating a grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801062/kinetic-js-creating-a-grid) and combine with something like: [Jquery drag and drop and snap to grid in kineticJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494292/jquery-drag-and-drop-and-snap-to-grid-in-kineticjs) or [Snap to grid operation using images,kinetic.js,javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478427/snap-to-grid-operation-using-images-kinetic-js-javascript) to get the snapping you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There exist books about this topic, e.g.

- Supercharged JavaScript Graphics, see http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920013044.do